# Can a value of a discount % be calculated by multiplying the item %, by the item value?

Tags: percentages

Can a value of a discount % be calculated by multiplying the item %, by the item value ?

Eg. if an item is on sale for $125 with a 35% discount, is the following arithmetic correct ?

`125*0.65 = 81.25`

Comment: Yes, that is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is correct. There is an issue though as to whether you round up or round down if you encounter a fractional cent. Usually this works in favor of the seller, and you would round up. If you encounter this in some kind of assigned problem, though, you should round however they ask.